# wordcloud encoding issues R shinyapps.io, UTF-8 not rendering properly

Tags: r, encoding, shiny, shinyapps, rsconnect

I am having an issue where my `wordcloud::wordcloud()` renders properly with Chinese characters encoded in UTF-8 when I run my Shiny app locally (Windows 10 machine), but when I deploy it to `shinyapps.io` the wordcloud no longer renders properly.

This is the code where I make the wordcloud in my `server.R`:

```
  wordcloud_rep <- repeatable(wordcloud)

  output$wordcloud <- renderPlot({
    wordcloud_rep(word_tab()$word, word_tab()$freq,
                  min.freq = wordcloud_minfreq(),
                  max.words = wordcloud_maxwords(),
                  random.order = FALSE,
                  colors = brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))
  })
}
```

However, other Chinese characters in my app deployed on `shinyapps.io` show up correctly, as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IArvE.png).

I tried setting `options(encoding = "UTF-8")` as some people do [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rsconnect/issues/123), but it does not seem to resolve the issue.

Someone else has had a similar problem with Korean characters, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39119094/wordcloud-encoding-in-shinyapps).

Does anyone know if it has something to do with `rsconnect`, or maybe how the `wordcloud` is generated in the `wordcloud` package?

**EDIT: I used the `wordcloud2::wordcloud2()` function instead and it rendered properly without me having to make any other changes.**

Comment: I think you should refer to [this](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/unicode-characters.html). In brief, you need to add a Chinese font to the system.

Comment: Thank you, this is a helpful resource!